# Most efficient ordering post database design

Tags: sql, design-patterns, database-design

I have `posts` table that is has `post_order` column. I store order of each post in it. when I change the order of a row from 25 to 15, I should update all the row from 15 to end. 
It's good for few rows, But in thousands rows it's worst.

Is there any better design for ordering posts, that is more efficient?

Comment: good idea in this question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46204/most-efficient-ordering-post-database-design

Answer (score 0):

Why not change with related order instead of all the way down from 15? Lets say you have a table like this:

```
Post  Post_Order
----------------------
x       1
y       2
z       3
.       .
.       .
t       10
```

if you want to change t to be the first post, you can change t's post_order to 1 and set row which has order 1 (x) to the value you selected first (10).

Comment: that isn't my use case, I only want to move t from 10 to 1, don't x from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old BASIC trick (from the time BASIC still had line numbers), of leaving **gaps**.

For example (shamelessly copied from [Kuzgun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17611394/533120)):

```
x       10
y       20
z       30
.       .
.       .
t       100
```

Then moving `t` to, say, second place would involve updating just one row:

```
x       10
t       15
y       20
z       30
.       .
.       .
```

Of course, you'll still need to move more than one row from time to time (when they "bunch up" too much), but this should be relatively rare (and you can make initial gaps larger if that becomes a problem).

---

Alternatively, just continue doing what you're doing.

Unless reordering thousands of items is *really* frequent, modern DBMS on modern hardware shouldn't have much trouble with it - just be careful to do it from one command, for example...

```
UPDATE POST
SET POST_ORDER = POST_ORDER + 1
WHERE POST_ORDER > 1 -- AND other criteria
```

...instead of issuing a separate `UPDATE` for each row.